# Ubuntu gnome 16.04 OS install

Tags: system-installation, burning

Hi my current operating system is microsoft xp 3. I decided to install ubuntu gnome 16.04 and i downloaded the iso of it and burn that to dvd using infra recorder.But i cant find the install icon in dvd and and nothing happens when i load the dvd.can somebody help me resolve my issue.[DVD image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuH1t.png)

Comment: You need to boot a live session with the DVD. This implies you need to either change the boot order at BIOS or use the one time boot key. You don't install it from Windows (and you shouldn't be using XP as it has been out of support for 2 years or so. You're a sitting duck for any criminal activity).

Answer (score 0):

You cant install Ubuntu from windows. You have to boot from the DVD.
In Bios change boot-order, so that DVD is before Harddisk.

Comment: Changing the BIOS boot order isn't really a great idea. OP shouldn't change the boot order, but instead select `Boot Options`, and choose the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install Ubuntu from within an operating system (such as windows)
To install Ubuntu you have to boot from the DVD you burned.
Fully shutdown your computer, press the power button and press F12 until you are brought to a menu that asks where you want to boot from. (typically CD/DVD-RW Drive)

Select the Ubuntu DVD you burned and from there you can either:
A) Install Now
or
B) Try Ubuntu and choose to install later

Comment: hi i did as you said i booted the pc pressed F11 till i got boot options and selected dvd. after a while i got error like this   'A disk read error occurred press ctrl + alt + del to restart'.

Comment: Sorry, but this is probably something specific to your computer. This error could be from many reasons, but usually means you burned the dvd incorrectly.  I can't provide much more help without knowing your bios settings and what your computer is...